# how to add previous and next link for the posts?

Tags: next-post-link, previous

i would like to know how to link the next and previous post of the current post with in that category..i tried lotta plugins put nothing worked out and I am a noob in WP so kindly help me

Comment: Are you looking for code or for a plugin? Also, what theme are you running (just in case it becomes relevant)?

Comment: @m0r7if3r i want either code or plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good place to start:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link

As you will see, keeping the links to posts of the same category is as simple as setting an argument in the function.

I would give an example but there are really good examples on the pages linked above.

Comment: thank yu very much. that link is very much useful. If yu dont mind may i know how to use those tags in such a way i put those links with arrow mark images between my post.

Comment: sorry. It was below my post

Comment: for example to output a link that is formatted like this **POST TITLE (ARROW IMAGE ->)**

Comment: OOPS: for example to output a next post link that is formatted like this **[NEXT POST TITLE arrowimage->](http://example.com/next-post-permalink)**  you would use `<?php next_post_link('%link <img src="your-path-to-image/arrow-right.gif" />', '%title', TRUE); ?>`

Comment: Thank yu very much Bro.It was very much useful and did it myself. :)